# How load css and js in Urlrewriterfilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using tablib with template to load header, body and footer in my pages jsp.
For URLs Friendly use UrlRewriteFilter. The problem is when I pass parameter intUrl friendly, not load the files css and e js.

The page http://localhost:8080/admin/home, load normally and the file urlrewrite is so:

```
<rule
   <from>^/home</from>
   <to>/pages/home.jsp</to>
</rule>
```

Already the page http://localhost:8080/admin/servico/48331006151024222123772, not load the files css and js.

```
<rule>
   <from>^/servico/([0-9]+)$</from>
   <to>/pages/service.jsp?key=$1</to>
</rule>
```

There any way in which I could leave the path of the css files and js default to load in all the pages without happen this problem?